# Unable to show Progress bar and text view at a time

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, progress-bar, android-webview

Hi Guys I am trying to show Progress bar and Text view at a time but Text View only displays once and disappears. Below is my Java File:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public boolean show_splash;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        show_splash = true;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        //enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

        //loads the WebView completely zoomed out
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());    

        myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        //load the home page URL
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://mvc.myorange.ca/");
    }

    public void Visible(){
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView Text =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (show_splash){
            webview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            show_splash=false;
        }
        else {
            webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //logo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void Invisible(){
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //logo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("mvc.myorange.ca")) {
                return false;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,  Bitmap facIcon) {
            Visible();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Invisible();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

and following is my activity xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>

<ProgressBar
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="65dp"
    android:background="#0582FF"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the problem is that the text view appears only once and it disappears. I would like it to be displayed first time along with the progress bar which comes after the textview. can anyone point out where i am wrong please ??

Answer (score 0):

Make use [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) instead of ProgressBar, if you want to load the text with dialog

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.. try to remove this line
Text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
and tell me whether the textview stays there or still gets disappeared

Comment: i want to show the text only when the page starts loading for the first time and if i remove the INVISIBLE line then when ever the page will be downloaded textview will come into picture

Comment: so logically the `public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            Invisible();
        }` is getting called before ur plage is actually getting loaded. and that is making the textview disappear instantaneously

Comment: Do one thing.. just to try.. try putting the visible(); method in shouldOverrideUrlLoading instead of onPageStarted();

Comment: That's not an option as whole time the text view remains over the webview

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments for getting a better code.

-The name of variables should be in lowercase. TextView text.

-findViewById() is an expensive call, you should do it in the onCreate method and save all the views as variable to save calls, like you did with ProgressBar but with all of them.

Only a couple of good practices.

I found the error, the problem is that you put the TextView to extend from top to bottom and from start to the end, then it only shows itself.  Remove those statements!

Change the layout to this one and see the differences:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Texto cualquiera"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="65dp"
        android:background="#0582FF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I made all the changes regarding the good practices. and thank you for that.

but as i made the changes the textview still goes away, also the main URL redirects to other url which is used for logging insite the site. So can it be a problem and making the text view disappear.